# How to display a day before and after a date stored in a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, ksh

I'm trying to display a date before and after a given date stored in a variable.
I can do that without a variable like so

> thetgerwie:~ $ date -d '2019-09-09 1 day ago' +'%F'   `result: 2019-09-08` it works fine

but if I use a variable dte="2019-09-09"

> thetgerwie:~ $ date -d '(echo "**$dte**") day ago' +'%F' `result: 2019-03-04` I get the current date

Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `echo` to concatenate the `$dte` variable.

Using double quotes should suffice in this case:

```
dte='2019-09-09'
date -d "$dte 1 day ago" +'%F'
```

Answer (score 2):

`date` command supports arithmetic operations
example:

```
➜  ~  date -d '2019-09-09 + 1 day' +'%F'    
2019-09-10
➜  ~  date -d '2019-09-09 - 1 day' +'%F'
2019-09-08
```

**UPDATE**
please use double quotes

```
➜  ~  dte="2019-09-09"             
➜  ~  echo $dte
2019-09-09
➜  ~  date -d "$dte day ago" +'%F'
2019-09-08
```

Here's a good resource:
https://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2009/11/fun-with-date-arithmetic.html

I hope this is what you're looking for

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for your response ,but the issue I'm having a hard time using a date 
 stored inside a variable (echo "$dte"). I used echo but, it's not working.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check I hope it works for you

Comment: fantastic yep!! it works, but it looks like jmiguel posted the same answer before you, do you mind if I give the answer to jmiguel? plus he is a new contributor. if not I will give you the answer, because you have been very helpful. Thanks Again

Comment: it's fine by me :)